# routing using nodejs restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I created below sample server.js and in this I want server to load default index.html at http:localhost:3000/public
but it is loading route "/products/?query" at above path, please let me know where i am wrong in implementing.

```
 var restify = require("restify");
 var server = restify.createServer();

 server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
 server.use(restify.queryParser());
 server.use(restify.bodyParser());
 server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath()); 

 server.get("/products/?query",function(req,res,next){

 res.send("product listing based on query");
 return next();
 })


 server.get(/\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
directory: './docs',
 default: 'index.html'
 }));

 server.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("server is listening at 3000 port");
 })
```

I want index.html spa page to load and in controller I will call $http.get("/products/?query",param) to get product details.

Comment: Documentation says, that handlers run in order they've been registered. Try to change order public and product routes.

Comment: Thanks  vanadium23, it helped. I clicked on up vote two times, now it is not allowing me to do same for your answer. it is saying you have undone so I can't up vote again.